# Append string to linq-to-sql query

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have a form with some indexes based on a document type.

I want to build my linq-to-sql query based on those index. The user might fill just some indexes or all of then.

I would need somenthing like that

```
Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.indexMatrix[] IndexMatrixArr = (from a in context.sistema_Documentos
join b in context.sistema_Indexacao on a.id equals b.idDocumento
join c in context.sistema_Indexes on a.idDocType equals c.id
join d in context.sistema_DocType_Index on c.id equals d.docTypeId

where d.docTypeId == idTipo and "BUILT STRING" 

orderby b.idIndice ascending
select new Gedi.Models.OperacoesModel.indexMatrix {
idDocumento = a.id,
idIndice = b.idIndice,
valor = b.valor
}).Distinct().ToArray();
```

This built string should be buit early in the code something like

field1 == a and field2 == b

Is this possible?

Comment: I've read your question 5 times and I still can't understand it. Consider rephrasing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your goal is to create expression dynamicaly, as far as I can see. And there are no way just to put string in linq query and make it work in simple linq world - that's the bad news. But I also have a good news for you - there are some way exist to create your query dynamicaly:[expression tree](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb882637.aspx), [dynamic LINQ](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/07/dynamic-linq-part-1-using-the-linq-dynamic-query-library.aspx).